# Unable to retrive values from tables in cordova

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova

I am new to angularjs and phonegap. In my application I am using sqlitedatabase by using sqlite plugin. I am able to create and insert values into tables but I am not able retrieve those values. Please find the below code.

```
self.fetchAll = function(result) {
    var output = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < result.rows.length; i++) {
      output.push(result.rows.item(i));
    }
    return output;
  };

self.isTermsVisited = function(){
    alert('doSomething');
     return DB.query('SELECT * FROM Others').then(function(result) {
      return DB.fetchAll(result); 
    });
  };
```

the above method not returning any values.

Please help me.

Comment: You mean your query doesn't return anything (the `result` parameter is empty)?

Comment: My problem got solved. Thanks.